# Occasional link's handling

Tags: java, selenium

Main page contains more than 300 links, clicking on each link on main page opens new window (of course) with table. I always need table value from the same position, yet... sometimes (but only sometimes) that (needed) table value is actally also a link which opens new window after clicking on it.
If clicking on that table value opens new window (with new table) I need specific table value from that new window, if not (if original table value is not a link) I need only original table value.
I tried with the code below but error occured...

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='aodds-info']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"}
Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds

```
package newpackage;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
   import java.util.Set;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class newdist {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,   InterruptedException {

    // Open main page

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("Main page link");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Maximize main page window        
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

           // List off all links on Main page
           List<WebElement> lista1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".first-cell.tl>a")); 

       // loop trough all links on Main page

        for(int j=0;j<lista1.size();j++){

        WebElement link = lista1.get(j);
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".first-cell.tl>a"));
        String homePage = driver.getWindowHandle();
        link.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        // Window handles block

                Set<String>windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator iterator = windows.iterator();
        String currentWindowId;
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            currentWindowId = iterator.next().toString();
            if(! currentWindowId.equals(homePage)){
                driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowId);
                Thread.sleep(3000);

        // "clicking" on specific table value (clicking maybe opens new window)     

             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/span")).click();
             Thread.sleep(3000);

            // if clicking opens new window print specific value from table in that new window 

                try {   
            String s0 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aodds-info']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();
            System.out.println(s0);
                     }

        // if clicking doesn't open new window print current table value from current window    

            catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            String s0 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/span")).getText();
            System.out.println(s0);


        }   

          // return to Main page  
        finally{

            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(homePage);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            }   
    }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Forgot, actually it works ok , but when table value (from first  window after main page) is not a link then Java return error...

Comment: Can you add the html of the table with the errors?

Comment: Collecting table value is not a problem actually as much as this "is link-new window with new table value needed or is not link-collect existing value"...

Comment: Maybe the html is different when you don't have link

Comment: I don't understand, the error is in `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/span")).click();` or `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aodds-info']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")).getText();` ?

Comment: *driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/span")).c‌​lick(); is clicking on specific table value (link) whether it opens new window (with new table) or not.... driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aodds-info']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td‌​[2]")).getText(); actually collect specific value from that new table (if previous table value was a link) ,  as I said it works fine but when value from first table IS NOT a link then I'm unable to collect "original" value from that first table

Comment: OK, now its clear. Are you sure both tables (in first and second pages) has exactly the same html? looking at the error it seems the html is different.

Comment: Basically for me it's not a problem to collect let's say only all table values from first window (whether they are links or not). It's also not a problem to collect values from
second window (when value on first window is also a link which leads to second window when clicking) but somehow I'm unable to do this IF-ELSE job in the code or maybe it's all to window handle(s)... I don't know really...  IF first table value is also a link take ONLY specific data from second table , IF first table value is NOT a link take ONLY (of course) that value...

Comment: If it was the window handles you couldn't click and open another page either. Can you post the html of the table with the error? maybe you missed something and you just need new perspective :)

Comment: No problem I'll post html but I think inspecting table html (which is quite simple) it's a step in wrong direction... I mean, solution is probably easy : Table 1 (one of the values in Table 1 is let say 3.0 on position: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sortable-1']/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/span")):
3.0 - if this is also a link clicking on this value opens new window with new table and new values and it's not a problem for me to collect this values (from new table)
but if this 3.0 is not a link (clicking on it does not open new window) then only collect this "3.0" value... Simple when we talk...

Comment: I agree solution is probably easy. The fact that you don't have problem to click on the link and go to another page while you have problem just reading the text leads me to believe you have a mistake in your `xpath`, that's why I asked you to post the table html.

Comment: No it's not mistake in xpath, it looks like code does not react on TRY-CATCH blok for some reason and when program runs on the value which is not link (not opens another/new window) it retutrns error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='aodds-info']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"} Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds  ---Why it does not react on try-catch I don't know...

Comment: I found the problem, wrote it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NoSuchElementException` is imported from `java.util`. To catch web elements exception you need to import from `org.openqa.selenium`.

As a side note, using [explicit and implicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) is much better practice then using `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: YES, that's it! Thank you so much! Now it looks like silly mistake but the truth is you saved my day... ;)   Thanks again.